# IF Function in Excelwith percentages

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

honestly I don't know what the problem is but perhaps you might help me finding out.
I have a column A with percentages (positive and negative ones). In Column B, I would like to get the value "TRUE" if the respective cell in column A is positive and "False" if it is negative).

My formula in Column B for example for cell 2 is =IF(A2>0,"TRUE","FALSE").

Instead of giving me the correct value, I end up getting only TRUEs...
I also tried to use SIGN but it didn't work either.

Comment: Sounds like your data aren't being treated as numbers. Can you post a screenshot? What result if you put `=isnumber(a2)` into a cell?

Comment: No need to post, you're right! It's working now, thanks!!!